# Upgrading Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, apache2, cpanel, linux, centos

I'm planning to upgrade **Apache 2.2** running on my centOS 6.5 server to **Apache 2.4**, Does the new Apache version worth the update?

Comment: Be sure to run [yum update](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-useful-commands.html) if you do.

Answer (score 2):

An update always worth because by updating, you apply security patches and earn new features: it's always a good idea to use the last version of a web server.

There is a sum up of new features of the 2.4 version compared to the 2.2 version here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html.